# Creating my own SWC file using Flex 4?

Tags: plugins, flex4, flash-builder, swc

Is it possible to create and compile my own .SWC file using only Flex 4 / Flash Builder 4? I don't have Flash Professional installed and based on some people I've asked, it is made in Flash Professional. How can I make my own .SWC file if I'm going to use Flex 4 / Flash Builder 4 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

In Flash Builder , create a new "Flex Library Project".
Technically, the name is wrong because you can create a SWC file without any dependency to the Flex framework.

Comment: Can you give more details to that? I want to know exactly how to output the .SWC file?

Comment: when you compile your project, it automatically creates the SWC file

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fe6.html